# HTTPRequest does not seem to work (Registering a user in a web app)

Tags: java, android, post, httpclient

HEre is my RegisterActivity:

```
public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);
}

public void sendRegistration(View view) {
    TextView txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    TextView txtEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
    TextView txtPassword = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);
    String strName = txtName.getText().toString();
    String strEmail = txtEmail.getText().toString();
    String strPassword = txtPassword.getText().toString();

    if (strName.isEmpty() || strEmail.isEmpty() || strPassword.isEmpty()) {
        // One or more fields are empty
        Toast toast = Toast
                .makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        "One or more fields have been left blank. Please fill them in.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    } else {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.******.**/register.php");
        try {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", strName));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", strEmail));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", strPassword));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            startActivityForResult(new Intent(view.getContext(),
                    RegFinishActivity.class), 0);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

}

What my goal is, is to validate that the email, name, password is not empty then send a request to my server, but when I run this code on my device, it says "Applciation has crashed". I am running Android 4.0.3, and infact do have the permission for internet in the manifest. What else could cause this problem? Without the http request, this runs fine, and the next view is shown.

LogCat log from start to finish of application:

```
01-08 08:58:06.793: D/dalvikvm(20672): GC_CONCURRENT freed 60K, 3% free 9439K/9671K, paused 4ms+6ms
01-08 08:58:06.929: D/OpenGLRenderer(20672): Flushing caches (mode 0)
01-08 08:58:15.597: D/AndroidRuntime(20672): Shutting down VM
01-08 08:58:15.597: W/dalvikvm(20672): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a2b1f8)
01-08 08:58:15.609: E/AndroidRuntime(20672): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-08 08:58:15.609: E/AndroidRuntime(20672): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
01-08 08:58:15.609: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3044)
01-08 08:58:15.609: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
01-08 08:58:15.609: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
01-08 08:58:15.609: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
01-08 08:58:15.609: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-08 08:58:15.609: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-08 08:58:15.609: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-08 08:58:15.609: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-08 08:58:15.609: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-08 08:58:15.609: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-08 08:58:15.609: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-08 08:58:15.609: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-08 08:58:15.609: E/AndroidRuntime(20672): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-08 08:58:15.609: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-08 08:58:15.609: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-08 08:58:15.609: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3039)
01-08 08:58:15.609: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    ... 11 more
01-08 08:58:15.609: E/AndroidRuntime(20672): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
01-08 08:58:15.609: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
01-08 08:58:15.609: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
01-08 08:58:15.609: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
01-08 08:58:15.609: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
01-08 08:58:15.609: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
01-08 08:58:15.609: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
01-08 08:58:15.609: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
01-08 08:58:15.609: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
01-08 08:58:15.609: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
01-08 08:58:15.609: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
01-08 08:58:15.609: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
01-08 08:58:15.609: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at sms.web.RegisterActivity.sendRegistration(RegisterActivity.java:58)
01-08 08:58:15.609: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    ... 14 more
01-08 08:58:18.336: I/Process(20672): Sending signal. PID: 20672 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you requested internet permission in your manifest file?

Add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

in your manifest file above the application tag

Please post your logcat log if you have done this and you still encounter the error.

As said in my comment, you should use an AsyncTask to perform this task outside of the main Thread. Something like this, but then with correct variable scopes. This class should be added inside you RegisterActivity class as an inner class. YOu can then launch the task by:

```
new SendRegisterationTask().execute();



private class SendRegistrationTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // prepare the request
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.******.**/register.php");
        try {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", strName));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", strEmail));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", strPassword));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            startActivityForResult(new Intent(view.getContext(),
                    RegFinishActivity.class), 0);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // Do what you want after the request has been handled
    }
}
```

Some of the stuff in the doInBackground could be done in the postExecute or the preExecute like the activity launch.

Comment: I do have the permission in the manifest, but it still doesnt work. Now updated the question with the logcat from start to end of application, Which is 3 views: First one is a simple tap to continue, second one is the 3 textviews which are validated, then third one /should/ show after the request is finished, but crashes before it can.

Comment: This helps a lot, which line is line 58 in your  registerActivity class? I cannot see the imports here.

Comment: Line 58 is `HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);`. Thanks for the help, it is really appreciated. Here is the full RegisterActivity.java: http://pastebin.com/mzxTwma2

Comment: ou should use an AsyncTask to do this, you are doing the internet request on the main thread which is not allowed. It's possible that the service isn't available, or takes a long ammount of time.

Answer (score 0):

The LogCat output is clear: you are running network operations on the main thread which is forbidden. See the [NetworkOnMainThreadException documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) and the pages linked there ([Designing For Responsiveness](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html) and [Strict Mode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html)).

To avoid this error, create a background thread for HTTP communication (and generally for any long/slow operation), [this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html#Threads) contains some example code and more useful links.